# passing in a keyword argument with a variable holding the keyword string

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Suppose I have a function with this signature:

```
def foo(a=5, b=10, c=15)
```

Suppose I also have a variable, x, whose value is 'a', 'b', or 'c'. Effectively, what I want to do is this:

```
foo(**{x: 7})
```

But it seems like there may be a more straightforward way of doing this. Is my suspicion correct?

Comment: That isn't a valid function signature in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert What's the problem with the signature , please, I don't see it

Comment: @eyquem: That's because he edited it after I wrote that comment. It originally had something like `def foo('a' = 5, 'b' = 10, 'c': 15)`, which is wrong in two different ways. He's since fixed it (but it's still missing the colon at the end…).

Comment: @abarnert Thank you. But I don't see the label "edited", that's why I wondered. I still don't see it, I dunno if others see it.

Comment: @eyquem: SO doesn't actually track all edits; there's a grace period during which edits are merged together (with the original post counting as an edit for the purposes of merging). That's why all my answers usually only show 1 or 2 edits in the history despite being edited 78 times or so to fix stupid typos or broken links. :)

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the explanation. I hadn't remarked that since the beginning of my presence on SO !

Comment: @eyquem: Obviously you don't save as many typos as me. :)

Comment: @abarnert Yes. Because I read again my writings before posting, when I'm not in the tremendous desire of gaining ten points, ah ah. But I'm sure there remain as many incorect points in my english writings as you correct in yours !

Comment: Geez, fast on the draw. I thought about putting an edit note in there, but I thought it would be totally unnecessary given how quickly I changed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you want to do something dynamic that's normally static, Python generally forces you to be explicit about it (because [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

So, in this case, yes, `foo(**{x: 7})` is probably the most pythonic way to write it.